# Inserting unique values from datagridview to mysql database table

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, datagridview, insert

I have a datagridview that successfully inserts the data from datagrid to mysql table. But it just inserts rows that already exists in the mysql table. If I assign primary keys in mysql table, it throws me the error that Primary key cannot be duplicated. Can anyone help to generate this query either by using NOT EXISTS, DISTINCT, or anything else.

My code is:

```
 using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO markeddeleted VALUES(@product_id, @product_name, @category_id)", con))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of these:

`INSERT IGNORE INTO markeddeleted VALUES(@product_id, @product_name, @category_id)`

That will ignore errors (but will ignore other errors too).

`INSERT INTO markeddeleted (product_id,product_name,category_id) VALUES(@product_id, @product_name, @category_id) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_name=@product_name`

That will update the rows where the duplicate keys exist.

Comment: When I use the second query, it throws an MySqlException was unhandled: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET product_name='pro_name" at line1